# Error "MSB3176: Specified minimum required version is greater than the current publish version"

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-2.0, cruisecontrol.net

I've got build server running CruiseControl.NET and recently it started throwing this error on one of my projects (.NET 2.0, C#):

> MSB3176: Specified minimum required version is greater than the current publish version. Please specify a version less than or equal to the current publish version. in Microsoft.Common.targets(2238, 9)

I've search the net, but could not find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the properties of your project.  The version numbers are on the 'publish' tab.  You should compare the publish version with the minimum version ('Updates' button).

Answer (score 2):

The project properties have a publish version (on the Publish tab), and an (optional) minimum version (on the Updates button on the Publish tab). Neither is related to any assembly version, and is just used for ClickOnce. If a minimum version is specified, it must be logical (i.e. not higher than the main version).

In the csproj, this is the ApplicationVersion/ApplicationRevision and MinimumRequiredVersion elements.

Answer (score 1):

For me, someone had switched the publish options to be "The application is available online only". Which caused the above error. Maybe it would have worked if they had also deleted the files in the publish location, but as it was the offline application wouldn't switch to online only and would just give the error. we manually uninstalled and re-installed them and then the next time we published we'd get the error again. Switched to "The application is available offline as well" and the problem was fixed. If it had been originally setup to be online only it probably would have worked fine.